# Accessing $this->request in view without having to pass it into view Codeigniter 4

Tags: codeigniter

Is there a way of accessing the incomingRequest class within a view without having to pass it in a data array.

for instance I did the following initially:

```html
public function location()
  {
    $request = \Config\Services::request()->getUri();

    $data['uri'] = $this->request->uri;

    return view('/path/to/view', $data);
  }
```

But is there no nice way of accessing $this->request directly in the view without having to pass it into view

I want to do something like this:

```html
<?php
    $colorClass = $this->request->uri->getSegment(1) == 'workflow' ? 'bg-warning' : '';
?>

<nav class="<?= $colorClass ?>" >
<!-- rest of code here -->
</nav>
```

without having to pass the request directly to the $data array.

Answer (score -2):

You can make your own helper function to return segment value.

```php
if (!function_exists('getSegment')) {

    function getSegment(int $number)
    {
        $request = \Config\Services::request();

        if ($request->uri->getTotalSegments() >= $number && $request->uri->getSegment($number)) {
            return $request->uri->getSegment($number);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Reference link: https://forum.codeigniter.com/showthread.php?tid=74755&pid=371243#pid371243